DSP Puzzle - Advanced Signal Forensics - Spread Spectrum PSD
Signal Forensics is the art of detecting likely culprits from the time and frequency spectrum of signals. I made that up, but whatever you want to call it, this is an extremely useful skill, especially for reverse engineering waveforms and identifying likely culprits of hardware implementation issues.
That said, today's Signal Forensic challenge is to identify key characteristics of a Direct Sequence Spread Spectrum (DSSS) Signal from the Power Spectral Density alone (where we had the opportunity to capture the signal with high SNR by either locating ourselves closer to the transmitter, or aiming a very high gain antenna directly at it).
This DSSS signal was transmitted using BPSK, using a binary pseudo-random code of length $M$ toggling at the "chipping rate", $f_c$. This unique code was repeated $N$ times for each binary data symbol. If the data symbol was a "1", then the repeated code was transmitted in-phase. If the data symbol was a "0", then the repeated code was transmitted out-of-phase. As a real-life example, this is identical to GPS C/A code modulation which is BPSK modulated DSSS with a chipping rate of 1.023 MHz of a unique code that is 1023 chips long, and a data rate of 50 Hz, such that the unique code is repeated 20 times for each binary data value (however, acquiring a high SNR capture of a GPS signal would not be realistic).
The signal in question was captured at a sampling rate of 1 MHz.
The power spectral density over the range of $-f_s/2$ to $+f_s/2$ is shown below:

And Zooming in further we see patterns of distinct frequencies:

Question 1: What is the chip rate?
Question 2: How many chips are there in each unique code sequence?
And if we zoom in even further we see an interesting pattern around each of the distinct frequencies:

Question 3:  What more does this close-in pattern tell us about the waveform?
HINTS ON 3: You are not seeing the effects of spectral leakage;  at this scale presented these are very accurate power spectral densities, showing the power distribution of the signal itself over frequency. I had determined these PSD's using the Welch method with a block size of 65536 samples with Hann windowing (resulting in a resolution bandwidth of approximately 23 Hz).
Below are similar plots where I vary one particular parameter that created the plots above. In all cases the global spectrum over the range of the first Nyquist zone is the same: We have a Sinc shaped power envelope center at $f=0$ with the first null at 50 KHz, and in all cases there will be 10 spectral lines evenly spaced with each sidelobe of that Sinc (except #1 where the spectral lines will not be visible). What is interesting is when we zoom in to take a closer look at those "spectral lines", where more information is revealed to us (except for Spectrum #1 where the spectral lines are not visible… why??). What am I varying? That is Question 3.
Another significant hint is to consider what we could possibly do to make those spectral lines approach impulses in the frequency domain, and specifically what property does a series of impulses in frequency reveal to us about the time domain waveform? Then when those impulses instead appear as they do here, what is the significance of that?  These are the take-away "Signal Forensics" details that would generally be helpful for waveform analysis.

This is a “DSP Puzzle”, please preface your answer with spoiler notation by typing the following two characters first ">!"

I have a further question you didn’t address. We can see in the vicinity of 25kHz stronger dipping which deviates from the overall sinc-like line shape. This is especially visible in the second plot. Can you comment on this? What is the root cause?

Thanks Yair for your comment and I was interested in that as well but haven't dug into it.  Instead of seeing a strong spectral resonance, we see an anti-resonance or suck-out.  It is quite interesting and I do wonder what it tells us? I don't have the insight into that yet

Since question 3 has been elusive I will answer my own question:

For Question 1 I agree with the other responders: The frequency spectrum for a random waveform with a repeating "base pulse" shape will have the envelope that is the Fourier Transform of that base pulse. In this case the base pulse is a rectangular pulse as a "chip". For a rectangular pulse that is $T$ long, the Fourier Transform is a Sinc function with the first null at $1/T$ (So the PSD is a Sinc Squared). Thus we see the chip rate is $1/T_c= 50 $ KHz, with the chip duration $T_c = 20$ us.   For Question 2 we zoom in on the spectrum which reveals that it is not completely distributed (as we would get if the waveform was random and never repeated). Now we see the second useful property that any discrete frequencies reveal a periodicity in the time domain: if something repeats exactly in time (for all time out to infinity), it can only exist in the Fourier frequency domain at DC, the fundamental frequency (which is the rate it repeats at) and all higher harmonics. Notice specifically we are seeing concentrated signals with a first harmonic just above DC, and then the 11th harmonic is in the null at 50 KHz! This gives away that there are 11 chips in the sequence before the entire sequence repeats and that the sequence is repeating some amount of times before being transmitted "out of phase" as a data modulation as detailed in the description. 50 KHz /11 is the frequency of that first harmonic, but more importantly we can accurately measure that by seeing how the 11th harmonic lands on 50 KHz. (If the the sequence was only transmitted once before being modulated then there would be no repetition and the spectrum would be continuous).   For the elusive Question 3, we zoom in further where it is revealed to us how many times the sequence repeats before it is modulated by the data (how many 11-chip sequences are transmitted repeatably for each data bit). The final plot as a hint shows us what we would see if we transmitted the 11-chip sequence once (a continuous spectrum), twice, three times, and finally four times. Note each time we see "the first harmonic" appear at 50/11 KHz, and if we were to transmit the 11-chip sequence forever without modulating it, then we would indeed see impulses at 50/11 KHz and it's higher harmonics. So note with that last example that we see $N-1$ nulls in the spectrum between the harmonics of 50/11 KHz, where $N$ is the number of times the 11-chip sequence is repeated before data modulation. With that we get the answer to Question 3 that we now know the 11-chip sequence was repeated 10 times for each data symbol.



 Here is my take on the first two questions in this puzzle:  ##### Q1: The primary lobe in the PSD of a DSSS signal is approximately twice the chip rate. Thus, if the chip rate is $f_{c}$​, the main lobe's bandwidth will be around $2f_{c}$​. The PSD $S(f)$ of a DSSS signal can be described mathematically. If the spreading code has a chip rate $f_{c}$​, the PSD $S(f)$ will have a main lobe extending from $−f_{c}$​ to $+f_{c}$​, creating a bandwidth of approximately $2f_{c}$​. The form of the PSD depends on the specific pseudo-random sequence used but can be generally described by: $$ S(f) = \frac{P_{t}}{f_{c}}\left\lvert\text{sinc}\left(\frac{f}{f_{c}}\right)\right\rvert^{2} $$ where $P_{t}$​ is the total transmitted power, and $\text{sinc}(x)$ is the normalized $\text{sinc}$ function.   ##### Q2:  The number of chips in each unique code sequence MM can be determined by understanding the spectral repetition pattern and the total bandwidth used. For a binary pseudo-random code of length $M$ toggling at the chip rate $f_{c}$​, the bandwidth of the signal is primarily determined by $f_{c}$​. Given a chip rate $f_{c}$​ and a binary code length $M$, the spectral lines in the PSD will repeat at intervals of $\frac{f_{s}}{M}$​​.


Nice! (+1) Just to provide confirmation, can you update your answer to include the actual numbers for the chip rate and number of chips per sequence? Also did you see there was a third question? That one might be trickier but given your demonstrated insights thus far I think you would know that one too...


 Question 1:The DSSS signal will have a major spectrum null at the inverse of the chip duration $1/T_c$. Thus, the chip rate $f_c$ is approximately 50 KHz. Question 2:  Given the nature of the repeating chips, spectral lines will appear at multiples of $1/(MT_c)$. Given that the spectral lines appear to be about 5 KHz apart, this yields $M=10$. Question 3:This one was a bit tougher. Considering that the width of the lobes is about 1 KHz, this may mean that the total signal is approximately 2 ms long.


+1 for getting Question 1 correct (exactly). Question 2 is stated correctly but the answer for $M$ is incorrect (and would be easy to determine more accurately from the middle plot as the zoomed in PSD where you see the nulls and number of spectral lines in each sidelobe...)   Question 3 is still elusive: the total signal I simulated here was over 4 seconds long.
